# Count applied to adjacent characters on long string in perl, performance

Tags: string, performance, perl, substring

I have a very long string, at least 90MB (no upper limit, but lets assume it doesn't blow up the system). It consists of single characters, with a delimiter in between each. eg. `a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,e`

For each adjacent pair `p,c` of characters (minus the delimiter), I want to count the times `p` is greater than `c` (lexicographically, ascii).

The string is fed via `stdin` on my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $c; #current
my $p = 0; #previous
my $r = 0; #result

my $i = -1; #= 0
my $IN = <STDIN>;

$IN =~ tr/ //d; #delim is space here, remove them
my $K = length($IN);
while( ++$i < $K ){
    $c = substr($IN,$i,1);
    #$i+=2;
    if($c<$p){++$r;}

    #repeat to avoid an assignment
    if( ++$i == $K ){ #>=
        last;
    }
    $p = substr($IN,$i,1);
    if($p<$c){++$r;}
    #$i+=2;
}

say $r; #given 'a b c b a b a' it should print 3 for the pairs (c,b),(b,a),(b,a)
        #given 'a b c d e a b c d e' it should print 1 for the pair (e,a)
```

This code takes, for test files with size: 200KB: 0.02s, 19MB: 2s, 90MB: 9.91s.

I noticed that if I dont spend time removing the delimiters, and instead use the commented code alternatives (jumping in +2 steps), the code actually runs slower. This leads me to assume perl "manual" code is slower than using the built in engine.

Given the character list on the `eg.`, if separated by spaces, the code would set `$r` with `1`, because there are 10 characters, but only one adjacent pair is decreasing `e,a`.

So to perl experts, is there a way to count the instances where `p > c`? in a single api call?. I need something that would return `1` if fed the example string (for `e,a`).

Comment: Your comment says `#delim is space here, remove them` but you have said that the delimiter is a comma `,`. There's at least one of your problems.

Comment: no, i said delimiter is a delimiter, for example a comma, the code works, I just want better performance

Comment: Erm, okay, but it would help if your code matched your example data

Comment: I am testing with >90MB of data, so it will never match :(

Comment: You mean it varies through the 90MB?

Comment: Can you show example output as well?

Comment: @Borodin Doesnt matter, because they are always single characters, and it always starts with one, so you can ignore odd indexes. Assume the delimiter is the same though, no need for that complexity sidequest atm. Given the eg. I want some api call or method that returns 1 faster than my code, as there is only one decreasing adjacent pair in there, `e,a`. Ill update I guess...

Comment: @simbabque: Example output is presumably something like `42`!

Comment: ***"This leads me to assume perl "manual" code is slower than using the built in engine."*** Exactly. The Perl engine is written in C and highly optimised.

Comment: Are the characters limited to a-z?

Comment: no, they shouldnt (they should be ascii), but feel free to keep it within a-z0-9, or assume strict a-z (or 0-9) if you can do something faster. Just point it out. I could use your answer as a branch.

Comment: Does this code have to be in Perl? The fastest way would clearly be to write a very short C program.

Comment: yes, must be Perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try leverage the regex engine.

```
use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 4*1024*1024;

my $pat = join '|', map { $_ . "(?=[a-" . chr(ord($_)-1) . '])' } 'b'..'z';
my $re = qr/$pat/;

binmode(STDIN);

my $count = 0;
my $buf = '';
while (sysread(\*STDIN, $buf, BLOCK_SIZE, length($buf))) {
   $buf =~ tr/,//d;
   ++$count while $buf =~ /$re/g;
   $buf = substr($buf, -1);
}
```

Test:

```
$ perl -e'my @syms = "a".."z"; print($syms[rand(@syms)], ",") for 1..90*1000*1000/2' >data

$ time script.pl <data
21634012

real    0m34.393s
user    0m34.306s
sys     0m0.084s
```

---

But since I had too use a look-ahead, I don't think that's very fast. In fact, it turns out to be twice as slow as a rather naïve approach.

```
$buf =~ tr/,//d;
my @chars = unpack('C*', $buf);
for (1..$#chars) {
   ++$count if $chars[$_ - 1] > $chars[$_];
}
$buf = substr($buf, -1);
```

Test:

```
21634012

real    0m14.206s
user    0m14.005s
sys     0m0.200s
```

---

Even using `substr` is better than the regex approach!

```
$buf =~ tr/,//d;
for (1..length($buf)-1) {
   ++$count if substr($buf, $_-1, 1) gt substr($buf, $_, 1);
}
$buf = substr($buf, -1);
```

Times are similar to the preceding solution.

---

The real gains come from writing an XS routine.

```
use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 4*1024*1024;

use Inline C => <<'__EOS__';

   IV count(SV* sv) {
      STRLEN len;
      const char* s;
      char last = '\x00';
      IV count = 0;

      SvGETMAGIC(sv);
      s = SvPVbyte(sv, len);

      len += 2 - (len % 2);
      while (len -= 2) {
         if (*s < last)
            ++count;

         last = *s;
         s += 2;
      }

      return count;
   }

__EOS__

binmode(STDIN);

my $count = 0;
my $buf = '';
while (sysread(\*STDIN, $buf, BLOCK_SIZE, length($buf))) {
   $count += count($buf);
   $buf = substr($buf, -2) =~ tr/,//dr;  # Have to account for odd read sizes.
}
```

Test:

```
21634012

real    0m0.207s
user    0m0.140s
sys     0m0.064s
```

(The first time you run this, it will be slower than subsequent runs.)

---

The regex solution made additional assumptions:

- The characters are limited to `a` to `z`. The set can be adjusted, of course.

All of the above solution (incl the regex solution) made additional assumptions:

- The system is an ASCII system (though it would be easy to adjust to not make this assumption).

The tests were run using 5.24.0 on a shared Linux machine with unknown hardware.

Comment: b,a returns 1, c,b returns 1, but c,b,a returns 1, I dont see the bug

Comment: @gia, Fixed. (I needed to look ahead.)

Comment: yeah was going to ask you to repost, [regex with look ahead is 200KB: <0.01s, 19MB: 0.02, 90MB: 7.75s], [unpack is 0.02, 2.16, 10.02], idk why it is slower

Comment: [subtr: 0.02, 2.74, 13.32] so slower, C beats the crap out of everything though

Comment: I'm using `tr///` with impunity because it's extremely fast, and presumed to be faster than having to account for commas later. Testing seems to bear this out.

Comment: It never ceases to surprise me just how fast `substr` is. But I don't understand why mere indexing into an array isn't faster. (Comparing array iteration vs. char-via-substr iteration -- it's literally index vs. substring).  I've been playing with it on my system and find them to be about the same, as well.

Comment: Re "*It never ceases to surprise me just how fast substr is.*", Really? I usually find it slower than a smarter approach. For example, the OP found my regex approach faster than my substr approach. /// I think you're asking about the `unpack` solution? The time is spent allocating and deallocating all those scalars and assigning them to an array (which creates a whole new set of scalars) basically offsets the 4 extra operations needed by the `substr` solution. [Note that substr would be way slower on "upgraded" strings, but the `binmode` on the input handle gives us "downgraded" strings.]

Answer (score 4):

Here are some thoughts on your code

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program that you write, and declare every variable with `my` as close as possible to it's first point of use

  You should use *meaningful* variable names (they shouldn't need comments) especially in code that you're showing to others
- Use Perl string comparisons `lt` `eq` `gt` when you are comparing strings
- Consider using regular expressions. Perl doesn't have a performant "string" type, but a simple regex match is generally faster than a call to `substr`
- 90MB of data isn't so big. 2000MB might start to be a problem depending on your system

#### Update

I'm sorry, I've messed this answer up. I've tested using `substr` and the performance nearly doubles. So this is one instance where it's faster than the regular expression engine.

I get 16 seconds for this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <>;
};

my $len = length $data;

my $prev = substr $data, 0, 1;

my $result = 0;

for ( my $i = 2; $i < $len; $i += 2 ) {
    my $curr = substr $data, $i, 1;
    ++$result if $prev gt $curr;
    $prev = $curr;
}

say $result;
```

#### Update

Here's a variant that should work. It iterates through the 90MB of data using a regular expression, and so uses only the 90MB plus two characters at a time to compare them

It takes 30 seconds to run on my system

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <>;
};

my $result = 0;

$data =~ /(.)./gs;
my $prev = $1;

while ( $data =~ /(.)./gs ) {
    ++$result if $1 lt $prev;
    $prev = $1;
}

say $result;
```

---

Here's how I would solve your problem. It assumes that every second character is a separator as you described, and runs in less than fifty milliseconds on 90MB of data

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @data = do {
    local $/;
    <> =~ /(.).?/sg;
};

my $result = 0;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#data-1 ) {
    ++$result if $data[$i] gt $data[$i+1];
}

say $result;
```

Comment: Was writing up an answer that said basically the same. Although I was thinking in terms of iterating `<>` one at a time using `$/ = ',';`

Comment: @Sobrique: I think we're supposed to assume that there's just a single 90MB line in the file, and we must pretend that we have no idea what the separator is! And that would be so slow!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: That's the record separator. It defines where in a file your `<>` will stop, and is set to linefeed by default. Localising it implicitly sets it to `undef` and so the whole file is read.

Comment: @Borodin the following input `a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,e` produces 8 from your solution, when I believe 1 is expected. I think you just have your predicate backward (i.e. P < C vs C < P).

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: That's right, I think. It's the number of intervals where the first character is less than the second, which is all of them except for `e,a`

Comment: @Borodin hmm ok, it seems like the problem statement says that for every character pair p,c count the number of times c is less than p lexicographically. This would be 1 in this case. Maybe I read it incorrectly.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: You're right. I missed that `p` and `c` had been switched. It's a weird spec altogether. Fixed anyway

Comment: How did you benchmark your code out of curiosity? Your solution was running in ~6 seconds on my machine for an 18MB file.

Comment: With my 90MB file I got out of memory, I assume its the array.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I used [Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark). It ran 201 times in ten seconds. I can't imagine what you've done that take 19 seconds! Are you sure your file is 90MB?

Comment: @l'L'l: You're right that a cache would help, but the main time is taken in reading ~100MB data which will take about one second on an average hard disk. The processing is insignificant.

Comment: about 450MB available, the test file is exactly 96.8MB, every two bits is an element in your array, while I'm not sure how it gets to eat that much memory (if it was a char array in C it would be smallish), I'm certain I get out of memory though

Comment: I apologise. I've been working with a ***90KB*** test file. I'm working on a fix.

Comment: You have 450MB memory? That's miniscule

Comment: using more than 4x the memory seems wasteful, feel free to answer without regards to space, but please add how much space it would need.

Comment: @gia: I've written an update that avoids expanding the data into an array. It runs in 30 seconds on my system

Comment: @gia I was just about to write up an answer with reading into an array, expecting it to be faster (and certainly much simpler coding-wise). It shouldn't take so much more RAM? (Can you not get to work with more memory?  That is really, really small.)  However, the regex solution is nice, too.

Comment: @gia: See my new update. It seems that, this time, `substr` beats regular expressions

Comment: feel free to answer if its faster than my code, just state the ram (in O() notation if you can) if it will need more than 4x

Comment: @gia: Your original code doesn't look right to me (apart from the `>` instead of `gt`). Surely you should be incrementing `$r` by 1 only if `$p gt $c`? But you're adding 2 or 1, and you're doing it twice!. Also, `$i` needs to be incremented by 2 every time. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: [substr (this is basically my code lol): 200KB: ~0.03, 19MB: ~2.99, >90MB: ~14.45 ]. [regex once/array: 0.05,error,error] [ regex loop: 0.04, 4.88, >20s] Your code answers my final paragraph question, my code calculates one more thing, ignore that I may just edit it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution that reads a single character at a time:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

my $c = '';
my $p = '';
my $delim = ',';
my $fh = \*STDIN;
my $acc = 0;

while ( sysread($fh, $c, 1) ) {
  next if $c eq $delim;
  $acc++ if $p && $c le $p;
  $p = $c;
}
say $acc;

# echo -n 'a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,e' | perl test.pl
# 1
```

Solution ran on a ~18MB file in 4.93s

Comment: I would imagine `read` would be faster than `sysread` because of the user-side buffer. Still, both sound rather expensive compared to maintaining your own buffer.

Comment: @ikegami yeah, definitely agree. This was a pretty naive first pass.